Hauppauge DVB Tuner 24.04 Firmware issue
I have just updated from 22.04 to 24.04.
The old system required me to move "dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw" to /lib/firmware where I could reboot and then finalise settings the tuner in Kaffeine.
Now once the file has been copied, nothing happens.

sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-hauppauge - nothing
Download from Github and sudo mv dvb-demod-si2168-b40-01.fw /lib/firmware - nothing

Can someone offer some insight please?
